# AVX-optimized addition of two vectors containing only 3 elements

Tags: optimization, x86, simd, avx

I have some code like this:

```
void add_v3_v3(float r[3], const float a[3])
{
  r[0] += a[0];
  r[1] += a[1];
  r[2] += a[2];
}
```

I'd like to convert this into AVX code, but as I understand it AVX would only work if the vectors have four elements (x, y, z, w) whereas here I only have three elements (x, y, z). Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you just ignore 4th value?

Comment: AVX has [masked load and store](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vmaskmov), so you could do a 128-bit load and store with the highest dword masked off.  Then use `addps/vaddps` as normal for the addition; there'll be a zero in the high dword that you just ignore.

Comment: This could be figured out in isolation, but is there any context that might be relevant? For example, it already matters whether the arguments are expected to originally come from memory or not (if they don't come from memory, it would be better to avoid going through a pointless store/reload)

Comment: The arguments are two vectors in some 3D work, they’ll be in memory.

Comment: Masked stores are fairly slow on AMD (and masked loads still cost extra); ideally you can just pad your arrays with a dummy 4th element so you can do a normal 4-element operation.

Comment: If you have lots of these to add and they're contiguous in memory, then you could do four 3-element vectors at a time (12 floats) by loading and adding them as three 4-element vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to get them to vectorise into AVX is to simply think in terms of arrays, e.g.

```cpp
// this does not vectorise
void add_v3_v3(float r[3], const float a[3])
{
  r[0] += a[0];
  r[1] += a[1];
  r[2] += a[2];
}  

// ... but this will
void add_many_v3_v3(float r[], const float a[], int count)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    add_v3_v3(r + i*3, a + i*3);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6vhnWrh3a

which generates an inner loop that uses the 'ps' variants to process 8 floats at a time using 256bit YMM registers:

```
.L7:
        vmovups ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rax+32]
        vmovups ymm4, YMMWORD PTR [rax+64]
        vmovups ymm5, YMMWORD PTR [rax]
        vaddps  ymm1, ymm3, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+32]
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm4, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+64]
        vaddps  ymm2, ymm5, YMMWORD PTR [rdx]
        add     rax, 96
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rax-64], ymm1
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rax-96], ymm2
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rax-32], ymm0
        add     rdx, 96
        cmp     rax, r8
        jne     .L7
```

or 16 at a time with ZMM registers, if you have enabled AVX512f, e.g.

```
.L7:
        vmovups zmm3, ZMMWORD PTR [rax+64]
        vmovups zmm5, ZMMWORD PTR [rax]
        add     rax, 192
        add     rdx, 192
        vmovups zmm4, ZMMWORD PTR [rax-64]
        vaddps  zmm1, zmm3, ZMMWORD PTR [rdx-128]
        vaddps  zmm0, zmm4, ZMMWORD PTR [rdx-64]
        vaddps  zmm2, zmm5, ZMMWORD PTR [rdx-192]
        vmovups ZMMWORD PTR [rax-128], zmm1
        vmovups ZMMWORD PTR [rax-192], zmm2
        vmovups ZMMWORD PTR [rax-64], zmm0
        cmp     r8, rax
        jne     .L7
```

The **WORST** thing to do would be:

```cpp
typedef __m128 vec3;
```

Doing this simply wastes the 4th float, which means you'll only ever get a 3x performance increase *(instead of the 8x or 16x above)*. Well, not entirely correct... the compiler *may* be able to fuse 2 of those vec3 additions together into a __m256 op, giving you a 6x increase, but it won't be as good as the above.

The usual place where this approach breaks down however, are dot and cross products.

```cpp
float dot_v3_v3(float a[3], const float b[3])
{
  return a[0] * b[0] +
         a[1] * b[1] +
         a[2] * b[2];

}
```

in general SIMD instructions like to do the same operation on each lane. The dot & cross products involve operations across lanes, and so will either end up ignoring SIMD, or produce some slightly sub-optimal SIMD usage with a lot of shuffling of data about.

The only practical way to avoid this, is to convert your code to a structure of arrays format (SOA). E.g.

```cpp
struct float16 {
   float f[16];
   float operator [](int i) const { return f[i]; }
   float& operator [](int i) { return f[i]; }
};

struct vec3x16 {
   float16 x;
   float16 y;
   float16 z;
};

float16 dot_v3_v3_x16(vec3x16 a, vec3x16 b) {
   float16 r;
   for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
   {
     r[i] = a.x[i] * b.x[i] +
            a.y[i] * b.y[i] +
            a.z[i] * b.z[i];
   }
   return r;
}
```

which produces: https://godbolt.org/z/qhE5xW91s

```cpp
dot_v3_v3_x16(vec3x16, vec3x16):
        push    rbp
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     rbp, rsp
        vmovups zmm1, ZMMWORD PTR [rbp+272]
        vmulps  zmm0, zmm1, ZMMWORD PTR [rbp+80]
        vmovups zmm2, ZMMWORD PTR [rbp+208]
        vfmadd231ps     zmm0, zmm2, ZMMWORD PTR [rbp+16]
        vmovups zmm3, ZMMWORD PTR [rbp+336]
        vfmadd231ps     zmm0, zmm3, ZMMWORD PTR [rbp+144]
        vmovups ZMMWORD PTR [rdi], zmm0
        vzeroupper
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

inlining would remove most of that, giving you 16 dot products for about 3 instructions (+ a few movs for data not in registers already).

Structurally however, using SOA code everywhere is *harder* in practice than just sticking to standard vec3 types.

So either ignore AVX completely, and just try to think in terms of arrays *(which will give you reasonably fast results, with a codebase that's easier to maintain and extend)*

or, work entirely in structure of array format, which will give you very fast code, but expect development times for new features to increase significantly. *(also be aware that some cmath functions might not vectorise to AVX2 or AVX512)*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info has some links about structuring your data for SIMD, notably Slides + text: [SIMD at Insomniac Games (GDC 2015)](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/) which talks about exactly this case: people spend a bunch of effort to "use SIMD" with one SIMD vector holding one 3D geometry vector, then find that it doesn't give much of a speedup.

Comment: Yeah, historically games consoles have tended to have fairly slow memory speeds, and processors with small cache sizes. Filling ram & cache up with unused w's does not lead to fast performance.... ;)