# Using neon/simd to optimize Vector3 class

Tags: c++, simd, neon, vectormath

I'd like to know if it is worth it optimizing my Vector3 class' operations with neon/simd like I did to my Vector2 class.

As far as I know, simd can only handle two or four floats at the same time, so to my Vector3 we would need something like this:

```
Vector3 Vector3::operator * (const Vector3& v) const
{
    #if defined(__ARM_NEON__)
        // extra step: allocate a fourth float
        const float v4A[4] = {x, y, z, 0};
        const float v4B[4] = {v.x, v.y, v.z, 0};

        float32x4_t r = vmul_f32(*(float32x4_t*)v4A, *(float32x4_t*)v4B);
        return *(Vector3*)&r;
    #else
        return Vector3(x * v.x, y * v.y, z * v.z);
    #endif
}
```

Is this safe? Would this extra step still be faster than a non-simd code on most scenarios (say arm64 for instance)?

Comment: A compiler will convert the instructions to SIMD automatically, if it feels its worth it. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/vGxd7WrMv

Comment: Also, if you are using Vector3 for 3D manipulation, do yourself a favour and just create a Vector4 - you'll need it in the long term for points and vectors anyway. And as a bonus its a natural fit for SIMD.

Comment: @MikeVine thanks for the input. Agree with you and did it already :). In my case, Vector3 is heavily used in gameplay scripts.

Comment: @ChrisMM some older android devices powered by armv7 do not support simd. So the availability verification should be done at runtime. For this reason I do believe that the native android compiler won't automatically translate stuff to simd. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Always ask yourself if the User is complaining about the execution speed or if you are missing critical deadlines.  If the answer is yes, then consider optimizing (at the requirements level first, then the design level and finally the code level).  Otherwise you are wasting schedule time (unless you have extra time in the schedule).

Comment: My answer would be pretty much identical to the one I posted here (about AVX, but principles are the same):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67852338/avx-optimized-addition-of-two-vectors-containing-only-3-elements/67897501#67897501 

Also be aware that you're using the wrong intrinsic!!!  You want vmulq_f32, not vmul_f32. 

If you still insist on using a float32x4_t for a Vector3, just typedef float32x4_t into a Vector3 type, rather than taking the above approach of continually converting between the two types. On NEON though, you're better off with a standard vec3.